# local representation of a holomorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Suppose $f:C\to C'$ is a holomorphic map between two Riemann surfaces $C$ and $C'$. How can we choose appropriate local coordinates $(U,z)$ of $C$, and $(V,w)$ of $C'$, such that $f$ can be represented locally as $w=z^d$. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the first lemma proved in _Lectures on Riemann surfaces_ by Forster if you need a reference.

Comment: @N.H. thanks! i do need a more specific reference!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(U, y)$, $(V, w)$ be an arbitrary local coordinates, then locally we have the factorization

$$w(y) = y^d r(y),$$

where $r(y)$ satisfies $r(0)\neq 0$. Then $r(y)^{1/d}$ locally in a smaller neighborhood $U' \subset U$. Then with $z = y r(y)^{1/d}$ then

$$w (z) = z^d.$$

Comment: Thanks! I did so and i thought $z=z(y)$ may not be invertible, i realize now i forgot to time $y$!!